# Simple httpcode monitor

Tags: php, object-oriented, http, url

I'm making a simple httpcode monitor as an example for teaching myself PHP OOP. I have written the code below and would be interested in having it improved.

In particular, I'm not sure about this line:

```
$httpcode = $website->get_httpcode($url);
```

This seems very inefficient to me as I have to to pass the URL back to the website class right after I have already done just that two lines above. Shouldn't it already remember its URL? That might be a dumb question, but in my mind, I've already made an object called website and given it a URL. Then if I want the httpcode of the URL, then I feel there should be some way for it to remember its URL which I passed two lines above.

```
class website {
var $url;

function __construct($url) {
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function get_url() {
    return $this->url;
}

public function get_httpcode($url) {
    //get the http status code
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    $page=curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $httpcode;
}
}

// create an instance of the website class and pass the url   
$website = new website("http://www.google.com");
$url = $website->get_url();
$httpcode = $website->get_httpcode($url);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. *Always* specify the visibility. Don't use the old `var` keyword, use `public`, `private` or `protected`. Since the class-member `$url` contains internal information, you'll probably want to [hide that information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) (you've already implemented a getter method so that the information can be read but not written):

   ```
   class website {
       protected $url;

       public function __construct($url) {
           $this->url = $url;
       }

       // ...
   ```
2. Every instance of this class seems to be meant to represent one website. But your method "get_httpcode()" works for *every* website (it expects a URL; this is exactly what you've already noticed by yourself). It would be more natural to skip the parameter and return the HTTP-Statuscode for the url that is bound to the instance (you've "remembered" the URL in the class-member variable `$this->url`):

   ```
   class website {
       // ...

       public function get_httpcode() {
           // ...
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
           // ...
       }
   }

   // Usage:
   $google = new website("http://www.google.com");
   $statusCode = $google->get_httpcode();
   ```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I couldn't figure out with get_httpcode() method. That's really helped, cheers.